# Linker error when building with Emscripten

Tags: c++, linker, emscripten

I have an existing C++ library that I'm trying to port to Wasm using Emscripten.

The library itself builds fine:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libFoo.a
[ 33%] Built target Foo
```

However, I'm encountering a linker error when building the test suite:

```
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable FooTests_Run_Wasm.html
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Tests/FooTests_Run_Wasm.html] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Tests/CMakeFiles/FooTests_Run_Wasm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
emmake: error: 'make' failed (returned 2)
```

Here are the linker flags I'm using:

```
-fexceptions                    
-pthread
--bind                         
-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1                         
-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0
-s FILESYSTEM=0                         
-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED=1                         
-s PROXY_TO_PTHREAD=1                         
-s SAFE_HEAP=1                         
-s STRICT=1
```

Comment: Are you linking with a `main()` function?

Comment: No. The C++ code I'm turning into Wasm has no main, it's a static library.

Comment: I think .html outputs are treated like an executable; they need a `main` to run. Imagine html outputs like an executable and js outputs as libraries. If you add a `main()` or chang the output to only js/wasm it should link fine.